# Show one child VM, then show another, after the first was closed

Tags: c#, mvvm, viewmodel, caliburn.micro

I have one parent conductor. I want to show first view-model inside it. Then after first one is closed (i.e. some operation is done), I want to show a different view-model.

I'm using [Caliburn.Micro.Contrib](https://github.com/kmees/CMContrib), where a **ConductResult** displays child VM in a *Conductor*. It has a cool extension method **AfterClosingDo**, which runs a coroutine after that child was deactivated and closed.

However, when I run another ConductResult using `AfterClosingDo`, basically this happens:

- first child VM is closed
- Deactivated event occurs, ConductResult runs AfterClosing action
- in AfterClosing, I open second child VM using ConductResult in parent Conductor
- second child VM is properly activated
- however, the deactivation of first child VM still isn't completed, and **null** item is set as active in the Conductor

First VM basically shows progress of a load operation, second VM shows actual data. After the load is complete, I want to show the data in parent Conductor (using second VM, of course).

So, my question: is there a clean way to do this in `Caliburn.Micro`, preferably by not overriding default behavior of Conductor, Screen, etc.

I was thinking of using **EventAggregator**, though I'm not sure, if it's the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar issue where I had a conductor opening a child VM, then a confirmation box would pop-up saying "do you want to close" and had fired a callback for the original items `CanClose` method which had the same sort of effect as you described.

The popup VM would close, but in closing it would fire a callback which was supposed to close the first VM.

My conductor ended up re-activating the original VM which was annoying. The order of events was:

- Open VM 1
- Try Close VM 1
- CanClose guard method fired
- Popup VM 2 (using same conductor) in CanClose of VM 1
- Confirm button on VM 2 is clicked
- Confirm button fires callback for CanClose and closes VM1
- VM2 Closes
- Conductor remembers that VM 1 was active before VM 2 so re-opens VM 1 after it's closed

In the end I just implemented an interface which fired after the close.

Child items which have work to do after they have closed implement the interface (`IAfterClose`)

Then I provided an override for `DeactivateItem` on the conductor:

```
    public override void DeactivateItem(IScreen item, bool close)
    {
        var afterClose = item as IAfterClose;

        base.DeactivateItem(item, close);

        if (afterClose != null && close)
            afterClose.AfterClose();
    }
```

This made sure that the callback wasn't fired too early. Not sure if this will benefit you (since I've not used the contrib library) but it might give you some ideas.

The only downside to this was that I had to make a fix to `DefaultCloseStrategy` as when the callback would fire it would throw a null reference exception in there. The fix I applied seemed to cause no ill-effect but I've not really looked at why the null ref exception was thrown.

I couldn't find any other way to do this since the last event that fires seems to be the deactivation events and they are still to early.

Comment: If you're interested, I probably know, why null reference exception is thrown in DefaultCloseStrategy.Execute(). I'm not sure if it's a bug or some kind of misuse of the framework, but I've filed an issue: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/workitem/301

Comment: Awesome, I looked into it a little and saw where the null ref was thrown but didn't go much further than that as didn't have the CM source/pdbs at the time - hopefully it will get fixed by the CM team. Thanks for the info!