# CanClose - new child in parent conductor to save document

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro, lifecycle

I have shell, which contains TabViewModel (separately as property, and displayed in View through ContentControl). In TabViewModel I open a document. VM of document in turn relies on LoadSaveVM for loading and saving of the document. Document VM, which is itself Conductor of IScreen objects, however uses child VM to display data of the document.

Everything worked pretty much, until now. I've implemented 'dirty' behavior, i.e. when document has been changed, it is marked as dirty, thus when closing it, user is asked, if he/she wants to save it, don't save it, or cancel closing.

All of this is handled through Caliburn.Micro's regular framework (`IGuardClose`, `DefaultCloseStrategy`, `Conductor<IScreen>`, etc.).

The problem is that when document VM is being closed and user chooses to save, I get `InvalidOperationException` from List's **Enumerator**, because TabViewModel's **Items** property changes (LoadSaveVM is shown to handle saving).

Saving is called by calling coroutine on Shell (SaveDocument), which is delegated to ActiveItem of TabVM, i.e. Document VM, which returns coroutine, that ends as soon as LoadSaveVM is conducted in TabVM.

From where I stand, two solutions are possible:

- modify closing strategy for TabViewModel
- modify behavior of SaveDocument coroutine of DocumentVM, which would end until after loading/saving is complete.

However, in my opinion, neither solution is very clean, at least in my case.

Note: document is actually a file, which loading/saving takes long time (thus LoadSaveVM shows progress of such operation).

Comment: Not sure but it sounds like you are opening another child VM in the conductor to do the save confirmation....so this opens another tab? Isn't that a bit strange? Wouldn't you just pop up a new VM in a window/dialog to show the save confirmation, thus avoiding the issue?

Comment: No, I'm not opening another tab. I'm just opening a different VM inside Document VM. Basically Document VM just encapsulates VM, which actually shows data, and another VM which takes care of loading/saving the data.

Comment: I had a similar issue - I popped up a VM in the `CanClose` guard to ask for confirmation. When the user confirmed a close, I had to make sure the closing was executed in the correct order. I ended up implementing an interface called `IAfterClose` (with a single method) and checking for implementation by the child window in the parent conductor. This meant that my close ran at the right time. Basically, yes I had to modify behaviour, but I also had to tweak the close strategy due to a nullref (but this was because everything happened in the same conductor so you might not have this issue)

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that, you [suggested this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465419/show-one-child-vm-then-show-another-after-the-first-was-closed) in my other question about conductors in Caliburn.Micro. However, I think I'm gonna go with the second option and modify save coroutine. But nevertheless, thanks for idea.